# Centos7 Httpd Server Hang

Tags: apache, lamp, httpd.conf

I am using centos7 When i restart httpd service

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

it show me this error .

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2015-04-07 22:25:29 UTC, end at Tue 2015-07-14 21:48:12 UTC. --
Jul 14 21:48:12 www.rise.global systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Jul 14 21:48:12 www.rise.global httpd[20042]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Jul 14 21:48:12 www.rise.global httpd[20042]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Jul 14 21:48:12 www.rise.global httpd[20042]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jul 14 21:48:12 www.rise.global httpd[20042]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jul 14 21:48:12 www.rise.global systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 14 21:48:12 www.rise.global kill[20043]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jul 14 21:48:12 www.rise.global systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 14 21:48:12 www.rise.global systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jul 14 21:48:12 www.rise.global systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
```

I check in server no others services is using 80 port using

```
[root@www ~]# netstat -tulpn | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2573/nimbus(spooler
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1412/nimbus(control
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      9327/httpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48000           0.0.0.0:*                           1412/nimbus(control
udp6       0      0 fe80::225:90ff:fefa:123 :::*                                2747/ntpd
udp6       0      0 fe80::225:90ff:fefa:123 :::*                                2747/ntpd
```

I know a solutions that killall -9 httpd and restart server . But i dont have backup server , i am confuse do that . Please advice me what is the alternative ans safe steps at this situation.

I am afraid about downtime.

Answer (score 0):

When i give killall5 -9 httpd , i was disconnect from my ssh , I need to restart server from web panel . after restart i found everything is nice.